# Why do we need to abstract classes instead of virtual ones?

Tags: c++, oop

I know there are so many questions about on this topic. However, I couldn't understand the exact need for using abstract classes instead of virtual ones. If I am not mistaken, an abstract class is also implicitly a virtual class and the only difference between them is that the abstract method has to be overridden in child class. So, why isn't virtual class enough? In which cases do we exactly need abstract classes rather than virtual classes?

Comment: There is no "need". Why do you think so?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "virtual class". So the answer is that we need the one because the other doesn't exist.

Comment: @KerrekSB So what is the "virtual base class"?. Sorry if I confuse the concepts.

Comment: @zarathustra: Virtual inheritance is another topic entirely, unrelated to abstract classes and virtual functions. It determines whether multiple inheritance leads to single or multiple instances of common base classes.

Comment: Sometimes it is good to be able to express a pure (virtual) *interface* that independent types (not part of a *base class* inheritance hierarchy) need to conform to.

Comment: In "virtual base class", it's the base that is virtual, not the class. The virtuality is a property of the corresponding base subobject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there is no such thing as a "virtual class". I'll presume you meant to say a polymorphic class (with at least one virtual member function, and certainly a virtual destructor).

There is no "need" for abstract classes (those with at least one pure virtual member function), but they aid in creating *interfaces* that cannot be instantiated, but only provide a bunch of overrideable member functions. It allows you to provide a common base class to aid in polymorphism, in cases where instantiating such a common base class would serve no purpose or would go against the grain of designers' intent.

```
/**
 * Instantiating `IType` cannot serve a purpose; it has
 * no implementation (although I _can_ provide one for `foo`).
 * 
 * Therefore, it is "abstract" to enforce this.
 */
struct IType
{
   virtual void foo() = 0;
   virtual ~IType() {}
};

/**
 * A useful type conforming to the `IType` interface, so that
 * I may store it behind an `IType*` and gain polymorphism with
 * `TypeB`.
 */
struct TypeA : IType
{
   virtual void foo() override {}
};

/**
 * A useful type conforming to the `IType` interface, so that
 * I may store it behind an `IType*` and gain polymorphism with
 * `TypeA`.
 */
struct TypeB : IType
{
   virtual void foo() override {}
};
```

Comment: It should be noted that `IType` must have its destructor declared as `virtual`.

Comment: There is something of a "need" for pure virtual functions: it might not be practical to implement the base-class function. For example, if it returns a type that can't be instantiated without resources that aren't available to the base class.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: It's certainly convenient in a plurality of cases.